# Email attachment size limit in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, outlook, logic, attachment

I'm hitting an email attachment size limit in Logic Apps.  I'm fetching attachments from Outlook in Office365, and there seems to be a 2MB limit to attachments - anything above that fails the job.
Any ideas if this is something configurable or an actual limit.  And if it is configurable, any ideas where I can change it?
Cheers, Jim.

Comment: The documentation doesn't state a hard limit or something configurable. This is more likely to be a limitation on file attachments in Outlook.com not in Logic Apps. I'm not sure what Outlook.com's attachment limit is.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Outlook doesn't have an issue with it - the mailbox can handle much bigger attachments, and it can happily forward the mails on, the attachments can be downloaded directly from Office365, etc. It's something within Logic Apps that's causing the issue.